# Grid background flickering (Metro app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a Grid with background defined as a ImageBrush in XAML. The image is quite large (about 1 MB, jpg). When I navigate to the page, first for about a second only black background is shown and then after a while the background image is loaded. It does not look very good. How to solve this? Maybe some image caching or loading the image into memory?

**Edit:** The image is 2560x1600 because of the highest resolution the app should support. Is there a ways to detect screen resolution and use appropriate image? 
I also read an article about scaling images on Windows 8 blog but I could not find any example how it works. The idea is that there will be a background for 1366x768 as 100%, 1920x1080 as 140% and 2560x1600 as 180% and the system picks the right one according to users resolution?

Comment: See my updated answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/78603167-121f-457c-b8d1-e15abfad0652/#78603167-121f-457c-b8d1-e15abfad0652) on MSDN before, but did not get an answer that would be helpful universally. If you want to be able to go to any page and immediately see an image - you need to load it before you navigate. If you want to avoid flickering - you can set the Opacity of the brush to 0 and wait for ImageOpened event on the ImageBrush before you animate the opacity back to 1.0 for a smooth fade-in transition.

EDIT*

The latest version of the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) has an attached property (ImageExtensions.FadeInOnLoaded) you can use to fade in an image when it loads which should look a lot better than simply showing it when it loads. There is a sample too.

To handle multiple image scales - you need images with names like SplashScreen.scale-100.png, SplashScreen.scale-140.png, SplashScreen.scale-180.png, then when you set an image source to SplashScreen.png - the right image for the resolution will automaticlaly be picked up. See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate thumbnails instead of the image with 1 mb

Comment: not an option, the app must look god on 2560x1600 and 1mb jpg is necessary as background